# How to convert a DATEPART hour that's military time for midnight (00) to a value I can use when I need it for a calculation?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datepart

I have this code which I'm writing into a stored procedure:

```
declare @StartTime time
declare @EndTime time
declare @Temp_StartTime time

declare @temp_StartHour int
declare @temp_EndHour int
declare @temp_StartMinute int
declare @temp_EndMinute int

SET @StartTime='22:30:00'
SET @EndTime='00:52:00'
SET @Temp_StartTime=@StartTime

SET @temp_StartHour=DATEPART(HOUR, @StartTime)
SET @temp_EndHour=DATEPART(HOUR, @EndTime)
SET @temp_StartMinute=DATEPART(MI, @StartTime)
SET @temp_EndMinute=DATEPART(MI, @EndTime)

if(@temp_EndMinute>0)
    BEGIN
        SET @temp_EndHour=@temp_EndHour+1
    END

DECLARE @Temp_Table TABLE
(
  StartHour int,
  StartMinute int,
  EndHour int,
  EndMinute int,
  StartTime time,
  EndTime time
)

WHile((@temp_EndHour-@temp_StartHour>=1))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
        SELECT (DATEPART(HOUR, @Temp_StartTime)) AS StartHour,(DATEPART(MINUTE, @Temp_StartTime)) AS StartMinute,
        @temp_StartHour+1 AS EndHour, 
        0 AS EndMinute, @StartTime as StartTime, @EndTime as EndTime

        SET @temp_StartHour=@temp_StartHour+1
        SET @Temp_StartTime=DATEADD(HOUR,1,@Temp_StartTime)

        if(DATEPART(MI, @Temp_StartTime)!=0)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp_StartTime=DATEADD(MI,-@temp_StartMinute,@Temp_StartTime)
            END
    END

SELECT * FROM @Temp_Table
```

It works great if you use any time value other than the 00:52:00 example I have up there.  For instance, if EndTime was 23:05, the stored procedure works great.  I did some research around DATEPART but didn't find anything helpful as to how to get it to calculate midnight at military time properly.

EDIT: When the code runs properly, it calculates the time in how many hours between start and end time and the idea is to store new rows for each hour into the temp table (eventually this is going to be saved to a new table for tracking outages by hour). It works find when I run it with 21:30 to 22:15. I get two rows reflecting 21:00 to 22:00 and 22:00 to 23:00 (this is the logic I want). But throw military midnight in there, and I get no rows returned as the calc won't compute the 00.

I have found examples in my database that show start times of 22:00:0000 and end times of 00:00:00.0000000 and then visa versa.  So one way WILL calculate, where start time is 00, but if start time is 21:00:0000 and end time is 00:52:0000 then no dice.  I get no rows returned.

Comment: In what sense is `00:52` ever greater than `23:05`?  If you rolled over for midnight, then wouldn't this code run an infinite loop?

Comment: You haven't said what goes wrong with the code as it is. Note that one big difference between EndTime being 23:05 and EndTime being 00:52 is that in the latter case, EndTime is before StartTime (within a single day).

Comment: Sorry about that.  When the code runs properly, it calculates the time in how many hours between start and end time and the idea is to store new rows for each hour into the temp table (eventually this is going to be saved to a new table for tracking outages by hour).  It works find when I run it with 21:30 to 22:15.  I get two rows reflecting 21:00 to 22:00 and 22:00 to 23:00 (this is the logic I want).  But throw military midnight in there, and I get no rows returned as the calc won't compute the 00.

Comment: It could be that EndTime is before StartTime in a single day and I just don't understand the conventions of military time enough.  One entry I found in my table had this StartTime and EndTime that I would need to calculate: Start: 00:00:00.0000000   End: 11:28:00.0000000  but the calc would still fail because of the zeros....

Comment: Can you explain in plain English exactly what you are trying to calculate here (rather than tell us "the calculation fails because of the zeros")? What is the actual calculation you're trying to achieve? I can't really tell the end goal from a simple `SELECT * FROM @temp_table`, but I suspect the logic you're using above is far more complicated than it has to be. Also, how is the code supposed to know (if the start time is 22:30 and end time is 00:52) that only one midnight boundary has been crossed? What if 22:30 was last Thursday?

Comment: There's no way for me to know how many midnight boundaries have been crossed, but it's safe to assume one in these cases.  These are server outages that need to be broken out from a range into a row by row insertion (eventually) by hour of occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not missing anything, this is what you could try instead of your loop:

```
DECLARE
  @StartTime time,
  @EndTime   time;

SET @StartTime = '22:30:00';
SET @EndTime   = '00:52:00';

WITH timerange AS (
  SELECT
    StartTime = CAST(@StartTime AS datetime),
    EndTime   = DATEADD(
      DAY,
      CASE WHEN @StartTime > @EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
      CAST(@EndTime AS datetime)
    )
),
hourly AS (
  SELECT
    n.number,
    t.StartTime,
    t.EndTime,
    HStart = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, t.StartTime) + n.number    , 0),
    HEnd   = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, t.StartTime) + n.number + 1, 0)
  FROM timerange t
    INNER JOIN master..spt_values n
      ON n.number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.StartTime, t.EndTime)
  WHERE n.type = 'P'
),
hourly2 AS (
  SELECT
    number,
    HStart = CASE WHEN StartTime > HStart THEN StartTime ELSE HStart END,
    HEnd   = CASE WHEN EndTime   < HEnd   THEN EndTime   ELSE HEnd   END
  FROM hourly
)
SELECT
  StartHour   = DATEPART(HOUR  , HStart),
  StartMinute = DATEPART(MINUTE, HStart),
  EndHour     = DATEPART(HOUR  , HEnd  ),
  EndMinute   = DATEPART(MINUTE, HEnd  ),
  StartTime   = CAST(HStart AS time),
  EndTime     = CAST(HEnd   AS time)
FROM hourly2
ORDER BY number
;
```

The output produced is this:

```
StartHour   StartMinute EndHour     EndMinute   StartTime        EndTime
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ----------------
22          30          23          0           22:30:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000
23          0           0           0           23:00:00.0000000 00:00:00.0000000
0           0           0           52          00:00:00.0000000 00:52:00.0000000
```