# I can't figure out how to read from an old table with my stored procedure and save the new results to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How would I get the results from the below logic that I want to place in a stored procedure into a loop that counts how many rows the original row will be split into.  So a given row may end up getting calculated to be three new rows in the end...or no rows....or one.  So I need a counter and a way to get it out of the temptable and into a real table.  I have tried updating the temp table and worked on that for hours today with no luck.  I have tried inserting all my ids into the temp table. I'm just plain unfamiliar with how to do it and have researched it quite a lot today.  Help is appreciated:

```
declare @StartTime time
declare @EndTime time
declare @Temp_StartTime time

declare @temp_StartHour int
declare @temp_EndHour int
declare @temp_StartMinute int
declare @temp_EndMinute int

SET @StartTime='2:30:00'
SET @EndTime='4:01:00'
SET @Temp_StartTime=@StartTime

SET @temp_StartHour=DATEPART(HOUR, @StartTime)
SET @temp_EndHour=DATEPART(HOUR, @EndTime)
SET @temp_StartMinute=DATEPART(MI, @StartTime)
SET @temp_EndMinute=DATEPART(MI, @EndTime)

if(@temp_EndMinute>0)
    BEGIN
        SET @temp_EndHour=@temp_EndHour+1
    END

DECLARE @Temp_Table TABLE
(
  StartHour int,
  StartMinute int,
  EndHour int,
  EndMinute int,
  StartTime time,
  EndTime time
)

WHile((@temp_EndHour-@temp_StartHour>=1))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
        SELECT (DATEPART(HOUR, @Temp_StartTime)) AS StartHour,(DATEPART(MINUTE, @Temp_StartTime)) AS StartMinute,
        @temp_StartHour+1 AS EndHour, 
        0 AS EndMinute, @StartTime as StartTime, @EndTime as EndTime

        SET @temp_StartHour=@temp_StartHour+1
        SET @Temp_StartTime=DATEADD(HOUR,1,@Temp_StartTime)

        if(DATEPART(MI, @Temp_StartTime)!=0)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp_StartTime=DATEADD(MI,-@temp_StartMinute,@Temp_StartTime)
            END
    END

--here's where it all goes horribly wrong
SELECT * INTO newTable FROM @Temp_Table
```

---

More information:

The answer can be found in an earlier question I had posed. I started this scaled down version of that question as I thought I had posted too much information for someone to find a point to help me. But that was not completely true as I got a great answer from another user.

- [Need to update rows from a stored procedure via IDs in a temp table - SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341080/need-to-update-rows-from-a-stored-procedure-via-ids-in-a-temp-table-sql-server)

Comment: Please don't keep creating new questions just because you don't get immediate answers. Edit your existing questions.

Comment: I wasn't trying to do it based on immediate answers.  I thought I had completely muddied the issue with my DATEPART logic being mixed in.  Sorry.  I'll point this question at your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, the last line, where it all goes horribly wrong, should probably be:

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM @Temp_Table
```

This is the standard way of transferring all rows from one table into another.  It is usually preferred to list the columns explicitly in the INSERT part and in place of the `*`:

```
INSERT INTO newTable(StartHour, StartMinute, EndHour, EndMinute, StartTime, EndTime)
    SELECT StartHour, StartMinute, EndHour, EndMinute, StartTime, EndTime
      FROM @Temp_Table
```

This does assume that the column names are the same in the two tables.  You can fix things up with names, if necessary.  Any extra columns in newTable not listed in @Temp_Table will have a null inserted; if that causes a constraint violation, the statement as a whole should be aborted.